# Facebook Marketing API - Keywordstats empty

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am working with ADs api and using keywordstats.
It worked well, now I am getting some weird responses, or maybe it should be like that.

I created AD 7 days ago, 24 days after using keywordstats and fields like, cpc, actions, impressions, unique_actions returned me good results, matched at what I was seeing on ADS manager. AD was live one day.

Now 6 days after after, actions and unique actions has only one element "attention_event"? Impressions by each interest are also weird, for each I am getting from 1 to 5? In total I have more then 5K impressions, how is this possible? I have tried with specific dates, for one day it returns this weird data, for other days just returns empty response.

Actions fields, 6 days ago contained and events from FB Pixel, now none is returned in response.

Is this supposed to work like this, or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I've also dealt with some bugginess with the `keywordstats` endpoint.

If you look at the [API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/click-tags/#keyword), you'll see a particular line: "*To query from a particular day in the last week:*". It seems like Facebook doesn't allow you to query for keywordstats that aren't from the past week. The discrepancy between metrics might arise because of this.

For some more context, I've found that even the last seven days isn't a reliable indicator of retrievable dates. I had to query each date individually (using `<API_VERSION>/<AD_ID>/keywordstats?date=YYYY-MM-DD`) and see which ones don't return an empty object. The dates that do return a metric are the ones that you should use in your calculations.

Comment: Yes, I saw that line in API doc, but still does not make sense, since I started AD again, and after 24 hours (in first did not receive any response) I am getting summarized results from all previous days when AD was running. This is weird, why am I seeing all results, instead of last week, right?

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily last week, but just a seven day period that Facebook decides on. Running it today and I'm getting metrics from last Monday (5/27/19) to Sunday (6/2/19).

Comment: Yes, it's just weird as hell, to be honest I can not figure it out, how and when to get real data?

Comment: it's probably better to post a bug report on Facebook

Comment: Yes, will try there, I wrote on Facebook groups for developers and marketing API, but did not get any response.